# Zaeed DLC Not Installing - Mass Effect 2

Tags: technical-issues, mass-effect-2

So Mass Effect 2 is free at the moment, so I've decided to give it ago.

The problem is that after I downloaded the base game, the Zaeed DLC pack begins to download (which is fine) but when the installation stage comes, it gets stuck at 0%. I have tried to cancel the DLC from my queue but it won't allow me.

This problem isn't allowing me to play the base game.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this for PC or Xbox?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to download manually from the old Bioware social network?

You can go to https://social.bioware.com

Sign in, or create an account, with your email and origin password. Zaeed: The Price of Vengeance should be there available for download as an exe file.

After running the exe file load up the game and should work.